# Parsing XML with (StaX) : Issue with <p/> ClassCastException

Tags: java, xml-parsing, stax

I am having an issue with parsing a "P" tag that doesn't close the normal way.

```
<p/>
```

The java parser throws

> java.lang.**ClassCastException**:
>   com.sun.xml.internal.stream.events.EndElementEvent cannot be cast to
>   javax.xml.stream.events.Characters

```
 <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <p>GENE_ASSOCIATION: BLA BLA</p>
        <p>BLA BLA: Purine metabolism</p>
        <p>BLA BLA: 2.7.4.3</p>
        <p>BLA BLA Level: 1</p>
        <p>AUTHORS:PMID:6182143;PMID:6244157</p>
        <p/> **<-- Problem here**
```

I am using 
`if (event.isEndElement()) {
  EndElement endElement = event.asEndElement();
}`

Comment: Please post your complete parsing algorithm, plus the complete exception stacktrace.

Comment: `<p/>` is not an end-tag. It's an *empty* tag, and STaX will give you both a StartElement and an EndElement event for those, as you'd know if you read the documentation.

Comment: Hey andreas, thanks for replying, the documentation say :" As with proper XML syntax, all container elements have corresponding start and end events; for example, every StartElement has a corresponding EndElement, even for empty elements." In my code I have both StartElement and EndElement. It works for all the tags except that empty one

Comment: Little Santi, I am using hthis tutorial http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaXML/article.html